# Coloring area between pixels based on thickness

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, nibabel

I'm trying to isolate the gray matter in a brain image and color it based on the cortical thickness at each point giving a result similar to this:
[Cortical thickness map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vYyX.png) based on this original: [Original brain scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvrbt.png)
So far I have segmented the white matter boundary and the gray matter boundary giving me this:
[White + Gray matter segmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4yIq.png)
The next step is where I'm stuck.
I need to find the distance between the 2 boundaries by finding the closest white boundary pixel for each gray boundary pixel and record the distance between them as shown here: [Distance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/feVSE.png)
This can be done simply with some for loops and Euclidian distance.
My problem is how to then color the pixels in between them/assign the distance value to the pixels between them.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import nibabel as nib
from skimage import filters
from skimage import morphology


t1 = nib.load('raw_map1.nii').get_fdata()
t1map = nib.load('thickness_map1.nii').get_fdata()

filt_t1 = filters.gaussian(t1,sigma=1)
plt.imshow(filt_t1[:,128,:])

#Segment the white matter surface
wm = filt_t1 > 75
plt.imshow(wm[:,128,:])

med_wm = filters.median(wm)
plt.imshow(med_wm[:,128,:])

dilw = morphology.binary_dilation(med_wm)
edge_wm = dilw.astype(float) - med_wm
plt.imshow(edge_wm[:,128,:])

#Segment the gray matter surface
gm = (filt_t1 < 75) & (filt_t1 > 45)
plt.imshow(gm[:,128,:])

med_gm = filters.median(gm)
plt.imshow(med_gm[:,128,:])

dilg = morphology.binary_dilation(med_gm)
edge_gm = dilg.astype(float) - med_gm
plt.imshow(edge_gm[:,128,:])

dilw2 = morphology.binary_dilation(edge_wm)
plt.imshow(dilw2[:,128,:])

fedge_gm = edge_gm.astype(float) - dilw2
plt.imshow(fedge_gm[:,128,:])

fedge_gm2 = fedge_gm > 0
plt.imshow(fedge_gm2[:,128,:])

#Combine both surfaces
final = fedge_gm2 + edge_wm
plt.imshow(final[:,128,:])
```

Comment: You need to identify the iternal and the external boundaries, then you can solve a laplace equation to find the distance normal to the boundaries, and a path between boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **DL+DiReCT**: https://github.com/SCAN-NRAD/DL-DiReCT

Starting from a brain scan (T1-weighted MRI) as input, [DL+DiReCT](https://doi.org/10.1002/hbm.25159) (https://doi.org/10.1002/hbm.25159) labels anatomical regions including the cortex and calculates a voxel-wise cortical thickness map (*T1w_norm_thickmap.nii.gz*). For every voxel inside the cortex, the intensity indicates the thickness of the cortex in mm.